# Why unbonding period of polkdot is 28 era(28 days) and why not 27 eras or some other number?

Tags: polkadot, staking, proof-of-stake

I`m curious about whether 28 era is a particular number, why not 26 or 27 or some else?

Answer (score 4):

The unbonding period has to be longer than or equal to [the *grace period* of slashes](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking#slashing). Otherwise the nominator would be able to send their DOTs out and avoid them being slashed.

I believe that the 28 days-long grace period for slashes is to allow enough time for community discussion and to cancel the slashes in case they were unjustified

Comment: also, 28 eras is relevant for long-range attacks.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering that question, it's helpful to know the number should be divisible by 7, meantime I just can't stop thinking about why is 28, and why other options like 35 days (5 weeks) are too long for that.